# Getting started with PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker-compose, phpstorm

I am setting up the PhpStorm Workshop, using this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/workshop-materials.html).

However when I get to the step about setting up the docker-compose.yml file, I keep getting errors.

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\phpstormworkshop>
docker-compose up
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 18, column 5
expected <block end>, but found '<block sequence start>'
in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 25, column 7
```

The file is the file that came with PhpStorm and all I have done is uncomment the Windows path.

```
version: '2'
services:
  debug:
    image: phpstorm/php-71-apache-xdebug
    ports:
     - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./workshop/07_Debugging:/var/www/html
    environment:
        #For Windows and macOS, replace the line below with `host.docker.internal`, which will automatically resolve to the internal address of the host Docker is running on.
        #For Linux, replace the line below with your hostname, which you can obtain by executing `hostname` in Terminal.
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal

        #For macOS, if you use a local Homebrew php-fpm installation, port `9000` (which is the default debugging port) may become occupied. PhpStorm will remain silent on starting listening for incoming connections. If this is the case, in the Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug, set the Debug port to 9001, and use the following configuration line instead.

        #XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal, remote_port=9001
  sftp:
    image: phpstorm/sftp-server
    ports:
      - "2022:22"
    volumes:
  #   Uncomment for Windows
       - C:/temp:/home/jetbrains/upload
  #   Uncomment for macOS/Linux
      - /tmp:/home/jetbrains/upload
    command: jetbrains:jetbrains:1001
  mysql:
      image: phpstorm/mysql
      ports:
        - "33056:3306"
      volumes:
        - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Any ideas why I might be getting this error? Have not been able to find anything on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should uncomment only 1 of these lines:

```
  #   Uncomment for Windows
  #     - C:/temp:/home/jetbrains/upload
  #   Uncomment for macOS/Linux
      - /tmp:/home/jetbrains/upload
```

OR (if you use Windows)

```
  #   Uncomment for Windows
       - C:/temp:/home/jetbrains/upload
  #   Uncomment for macOS/Linux
  #    - /tmp:/home/jetbrains/upload
```